# Do methods annotated with @BeforeClass and @BeforeSuite execute before @DataProvider in TestNG?

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I want to use `@BeforeClass` to do some test data setup and use it in `@DataProvider`.

Is it guaranteed `@BeforeClass` executes before `@DataProvider`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `@BeforeClass` and `@BeforeSuite` will get executed before `@DataProvider` in `TestNG`.

You can refer [testNG documetation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

`@BeforeSuite`: The annotated method will be run before all tests in this suite have run.

`@BeforeClass`: The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked.

Though it doesn't give a clear idea whether it will execute before `@DataProvider` or not, I have created sample test:

```
public class SeleniumJava {
    Object[][] testData;

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] data() {
        System.out.println("In @DataProvider");
        return testData;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setData() {
        System.out.println("in @BeforeClass");
        testData = new String[][]{new String[]{"data1"}, new String[]{"data2"}};
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "data")
    public void printData(String d) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
in @BeforeClass
In @DataProvider
data1
data2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is guaranteed that @BeforeClass executes before @DataProvider. @BeforeClass is seen by the compiler at class level whereas @DataProvider is seen by the compiler at method level.